# Checking user existence in separate user-service. Make use of JWT user_id or choreography?

Tags: java, node.js, asynchronous, architecture, microservices

So I return with yet another question I'm having about designing my microservices project app.

Imagine we got those two microservices:
**user-management** (stores user_id + other stuff about user)
**posts-management** (stores users' posts  and will obviously need a copy/reference of user_ids)

My problem is that I did think of basically storing the user_id in the JWT and make use of that one. This would work perfectly when an user creates a post but there comes a problem. What happens when an admin deletes the account of that user? The jwt of that user might still be available ( even if i use short-lived jwts like 15 mins) and he might be able to **create** new posts in the posts-service despite not having an account anymore.

Another thing I thought of ( again im a newbie so I'm not sure which would be the best course ) would be that each time we make a post request, we just create the post in the post-service without checking immediately, but try to send an event asynchronously to the user-service which would "CHECK" for the existence of the user. If the user service returns nothing then it's all ok, but if it returns something like UserDoesNotExistEvent, we would delete all the posts from the post-service. The problem that appears now is that id make those async requests ( even tho they're async ) I'd have to make them EACH time a new post is created. Is this ok? Would it overload the user service and the post service by creating posts which would be deleted soon after?

What should I do?

I want this to be quite effective, but this is just a final year project after all so it's not like it is a product I'll make money off, but I'd like to learn as many things as  I can about microservices good practices and tradeoffs.

**EDIT!**
Ok so have actually thought of something and would love to hear your opinion on this. What if when I delete an user and the user-service sends an event to the post-service, I don't delete the posts of that user, but instead store all the user_ids of the users who I want to remove. I could have some sort of scheduled task which would delete those "users_to_be_deleted" each hour or so and I think it would kinda fix the problem I had before, but of course users will still be able to  post things until their jwt expire.

Comment: Before you give access your user to do something with token, check the id existed in the db then do some sort of actions you can do this in the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is just to check with the `user` service on each post. The user service can return the existence of the user and any permissions. If the user is authorized to post, you let them post. If they don't exist, or aren't authorized to post, you don't let them. The `user` service should cache requests and then bust the cache when a user is deleted. Calling the auth service on each request like this is fairly standard and is usually implemented in API middleware.

Comment: Yeah but doesn't this add coupling to the user-service /auth-service?

Comment: Yes. This problem has CAP-like constraints. If you want strict authorization for posting and separate services, they'll be coupled like this.

Answer (score 0):

It will be an overkill to check if a user is valid or not every time. Your second idea is better.

However, there can be an alternative approach to this.

1. Instead of restricting the user to post, you can check user validity when displaying the posts. Even if the user is successful in creating several posts, you can choose to not show them on your App/Website. or you can show them along with user status (which most apps/websites do today)
2. Invalidate the token. explained in detail here: https://dev.to/webjose/how-to-invalidate-jwt-tokens-without-collecting-tokens-47pk
3. Think again, is it a problem that needs a solution? may sound ironic, but sometimes it may not be harmful. will there be frequent user deletion? if yes, then what are the different circumstances when user deletion would be required?  if it is most prevalent for new users, then you may want to restrict them from posting anything until they are verified.

There can be various solutions to this problem. However, in the end, you have to look for Risk vs Reward in solving it